Approximating the probability that two Binomial variables are equal
Let $X,Y\sim Bin(n,p)$ be independent R.V.s and let $z\in[n]$ be integer.
My goal is to approximate the probability that $P[X-Y=2z]$.
What i need is a tight enough bound with error that is at most $o(\sqrt{n})$.
The best bound i seen using basically CLT gives error of exactly $O(\sqrt{n})$.
The best i could think of is the following sum expansion.
But i have no real idea how to proceed from there.
\begin{align} 
 P[X-Y=2z] & =\sum_{i=0}^{n} P[X=i+z, Y=i-z] 
 \\\\
 & = \sum_{i=0}^{n} P[X=i+z] P[Y=i-z]
 \\\\
 & = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i+z} p^{i+z} (1-p)^{n-i-z} \binom{n}{i-z} p^{i-z} (1-p)^{n-i+z}
\\\\
& = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i+z} \binom{n}{i-z} p^{2i} (1-p)^{2n-2i}
\end{align}
Any ideas how to continue from here?
For clarification i want to approximate this from above and from below.
By the same term, and even the same constants, but with error of at most $o(\sqrt{n})$.
Edit:
$p$ can be a constant or dependent on $n$ tending to zero as $n$ tends to infinity.
For constant $p=1/2$ the question is easy to answer, but what about other cases?

Is $p$ a constant, or can it shrink with $n$?

It can be either, a solution to any of those is good

In the case that $p=\frac12$, $X-Y$ has a shifted binomial distribution so you get an exact answer.

Yeah for p=1/2 it indeed not difficult but what about other values?

Note that $X-Y=\sum_1^n X_i$, where the $X_i$'s are i.i.d. random variables with $P(X_i=1)=(1-p)p=P(X_i=-1)$ and $P(X_i=0)=1-2(1-p)p$.
So, assuming that $0<p<1$, by the local limit theorem -- see e.g. Theorem 1 in Chapter VII,
$$P(X-Y=k)=\frac1{\sigma\sqrt n}f\Big(\frac k{\sigma\sqrt n}\Big)+o\Big(\frac 1{\sqrt n}\Big)$$
as $n\to\infty$ uniformly in all integers $k$, where $f$ is the standard normal p.d.f. and $\sigma:=\sqrt{2(1-p)p}$.

Thanks, ill try to see if i can work with that!

What do you mean by "work with that"?

I just thought I'd record a cute "answer".
$$
   \operatorname{Prob}(X-Y=k) = \frac{1}{2\pi}
         \int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(k\theta)\,(2P\cos\theta+1-2P)^n\,d\theta,
$$ where $P=p(1-p)$.
If $k$ is not too large compared to $nP$ (a fractional power will do), expanding the integrand around $\theta=0$
as $\exp\bigl((-Pn-k^2/2)\theta^2 + \cdots\bigr)$ gives a pretty good estimate.
Proof outline:
From Iosif's observation, we need the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $(P/x + 1-2P + Px)^n$. Write the Cauchy integral using the unit circle $x=e^{i\theta}$. Since the answer is real, we can take the real part of the integrand, which is easy since $P/x+1-2P+Px$ is already real on the unit circle.
The unit circle only hits the real axis near the saddle-point for small-ish $k$. To handle larger $k$ (such as a fraction of $nP$), a circle of larger radius works better. The perfect radius satisfies a quadratic equation.

It might be helpful but why is that equality true?
